# ¿por que no puedo guardar una imagen jpg con php?

Tags: php, html

resulta que tengo este formulario para enviar imagenes al servidor desde un formulario:

```
$archivo = $_FILES['foto'];
$nombre_upload = ../blog/1670170497/foto2.png
if(move_uploaded_file($archivo['tmp_name'], "$nombre_upload")){
echo "se guardo la imagen";
}else{
echo "no se subio la imagen";
};
```

resulta que no recibo imagen en formato jpg, solo png, gif, etc, ya que no aparacen en el directorio $nombre_upload.

si subo un png el $archivo['tmp_name'] es igual a: C:\xampp\tmp\phpA30.tmp,
pero si  subo u n jpg, el $archivo['tmp_name'] sale vacio.
me podrian ayudar porque sucede esto?
gracias.

Comment: Tienes fallos de sintaxis, pues esto `$nombre_upload = ../blog/1670170497/foto2.png` debería ser esto: `$nombre_upload = "../blog/1670170497/foto2.png";`, y esto: `"$nombre_upload"` lo puedes poner sin las comillas: `$nombre_upload`. Pero suponiendo que eso estuviera bien, fíjate que todo lo que subes va a sobreescribir este archivo: `../blog/1670170497/foto2.png`, sea lo que sea... pero aún así no parece que sea el error que tienes, pues dices que el resto de extensiones si que te suben. Por lo tanto solo me queda que pensar que el filtro lo tienes o bien antes de ese código o en el <form>

Comment: Revisa el valor de `$_FILES['foto']['error']`.

Comment: si  gracias, el valor de $_FILES['foto']['error'] me da 1, por lo que investigue excede a upload_max_filesize, que es El tamaño máximo de un archivo subido. entonces como soluciono  ese problema por favor?

Comment: El tamaño máximo lo puedes configurar de varias maneras, depende de tu posibilidad para modificar el php.ini -o similar-, el .htaccess o para más rápido agrega al inicio de tu script: `ini_set('upload_max_size', '16M');` ajustando el valor a tu conveniencia.

Comment: oye muchas gracias